# Get an entry's grandparents with Playa?

Tags: playa

Is it possible to get an entry's grandparent? For example I have:

- Entry A

  - Entry B

    - Entry C

Entry C is a child of Entry B, and Entry B is a child of Entry A. How can I get the {title} of Entry A in the midst of a channel entries loop for Entry C? I'm on EE 2.6.1 and Playa 4.4.2.

**SOLUTION**

Here's what worked:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="pages"}
    {exp:playa:parents var_prefix="father" limit="1"}
        {father:exp:playa:parents var_prefix="grandpa" limit=1}
            {grandpa:title}
        {/father:exp:playa:parents}
    {/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```